# JAVA - getBytes return UTF-8 without BOM

Tags: java, excel, utf-8, character-encoding

I send a txt file by email in this way. File's data is in a StringBuffer.

File construction :

```
StringBuffer lBufferFinal = new StringBuffer();
// Put some text in lBufferFinal
FichierByteVO lFichier = new FichierByteVO();
    lFichier.setFileName("Statistic.txt");
    lFichier.setMIMEType("text/plain");
    lFichier.setFile(lBufferFinal.toString().getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

Adding the file in an email :

```
MimeMessage lMessage = new MimeMessage(lSession);
// Do thing tu put sender, receiver, subject etc to the MimeMessage
Multipart = new MimeMultipart();
BodyPart lMessageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
lMessageBodyPart.setText("Here is an email !");
lMultipart.addBodyPart(lMessageBodyPart);
lMessageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
DataHandler lDataHandler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(lFichier.getFile(), lFichier.getMIMEType()));
        lMessageBodyPart.setDataHandler(lDataHandler);
                    lMessageBodyPart.setFileName(lFichier.getFileName());
        lMultipart.addBodyPart(lMessageBodyPart);
    }
    lMessage.setContent(lMultipart);
```

The file I receive by email is by default open as "UTF-8 without BOM" in notepad++, or in excel (who does not recognize accents).

So I need to open with excel, so to have UTF-8 with BOM encoding.

Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: You can add the BOM, but the default behaviour is to not include it.  Most tools don't write the BOM when using UTF-8 encoding.  You need to set notepad++ to read UTF-8 by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I use .CSV extension and ISO-8859-1 and it works well !

Answer (score 1):

It is not convenient use the BOM. You can put the encoding of the mail like this:

```
JavaMailSenderImpl mailer = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
...
mailer.setDefaultEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
```

This will recognize the accents

Comment: I'm using Transport.send to send the message, not MailSender

Comment: this is quiet ununderstanding.... If I use ISO-8859-1 to encode the file, Excel does not recognize the ; character as a column separator...